# How to parse this json with php

Tags: php, json

I'm completely noob with json.

I need to parse a json that returns a result like this:

```
"response":{
    "status":1,
    "data":{
      "16":{
        "Offer":{
          "id":"16",
          "advertiser_id":null,
          "name":"My Offer",
          "description":null,
          "require_approval":"0",
          "require_terms_and_conditions":0,
          "terms_and_conditions":null,
          "offer_url":"http://",
          "preview_url":"http://",
        }
      },
      "17":{
        "Offer":{
          "id":"17",
          "advertiser_id":null,
          "name":"My Other Offer",
          "description":null,
          "require_approval":"0",
          "require_terms_and_conditions":0,
          "terms_and_conditions":null,
          "offer_url":"http://",
          "preview_url":"http://",
        }
      },
    },
    "errors":[]
  }
```

I need to access all offers name, but I'm not able to access trying this :

```
$url = "jsonurl";

$string = file_get_contents($url);
$json_a=json_decode($string,true);

foreach ($json_a['data']['offer'] as $offer_a) {
  echo  $offer_a[name];
}
```

What I'm doing wrong ??

thank you all in advance.

Comment: What does `var_dump($json_a);` show?

Comment: Before the foreach, add var_dump($json_a); and take a look at what the decoded data structure looks like. Perhaps paste it here, and it will be much easier to give you code to get the data you want.

Comment: You have show only an excerpt, but I assume your actual structure is more [like this](http://array.include-once.org/?foreach=1&assoc=1&json=%7B%0D%0A%22response%22%3A%7B%0D%0A%22data%22%3A%7B%0D%0A++%2216%22%3A%7B%0D%0A++++%22Offer%22%3A%7B%0D%0A++++++%22id%22%3A%2216%22%2C%0D%0A++++++%22name%22%3A%22My+Offer%22%2C%0D%0A++++++%22description%22%3Anull%0D%0A++++%7D%0D%0A++%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%7D). So note that you also need `["response"]` for the foreach.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answers here's a part of the dump, I need to access all offers names:

Comment: array(2) { ["request"]=> array(8) { ["Format"]=> string(4) "json" ["Target"]=> string(5) "Offer" ["Method"]=> string(7) "findAll" ["Service"]=> string(9) "U2C" ["Version"]=> string(1) "2" ["NetworkId"]=> string(10) "network" ["NetworkToken"]=> string(30) "NETQ5R0Z" ["filters"]=> array(1) { ["Offer.status"]=> string(6) "active" } } ["response"]=> array(3) { ["status"]=> int(1) ["data"]=> array(127) { [264]=> array(1) { ["Offer"]=> array(74) { ["id"]=> string(3) "264" ["advertiser_id"]=> string(3) "512" ["name"]=> string(42) "Offer 1" ["description"]=> string(1086) ...

Comment: @DaveRandom, above you can find a part of the dump

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be skipping the `16`. But this is easily debugged by doing this.

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($json_a);
die();
```

This will display the tree in an array/object. In this case an array.

But I guess this will work:

```
foreach ($json_a['response']['data']['16']['Offer'] as $offer_a) {
  echo  $offer_a['name'];
}
```

If you need all offer names:

```
foreach ($json_a['response']['data'] as $offer){
    echo $offer['Offer']['name'];
}
```

Comment: Close, but the 'Offer' key should be capitalized.

Comment: thanks @Topener, but the above code is giving me a Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Comment: @Jose please add the full JSON in your question, there probably is something missing there. According to your snippet it should work.

Comment: @jprofitt Offer is an array. json_decode with the second parameter `true` will return arrays instead of objects: http://php.net/json_decode

Comment: @Topener My bad, skipped over that parameter when I was reading the code!