# parse JSON data in PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing, mobile

I have a mobile application to send data to server in JSON format.

In php program, with the syntax … `error_log(print_r($obj,true));` I can see the values ....

```
[05-Jun-2014 12:25:36] Array
(
    [value1] => 2
    [value2] => This was sent from ios to server
)
```

I want to parse to insert in my table

```
function redeem() {
    // Check for required parameters
        $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $obj = json_decode($json,true);
        error_log(print_r($obj,true));
        $rows = array();
        foreach($array[] as $key => $value)
        //foreach($obj as $item)
        {
            $rows[] = "('" . $key . "', '" . $value . "')"; //This is line 32
            $stmt = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO prueba (id,nombre)
                                        VALUES (%d,%s)',$item->id_cliente,$item->nombre) or die(mysqli_error($this->db));
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    }
```

But I have gotten a error message ...

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: key in
>   /home/futchoco/public_html/WebService/test_subir2.php on line 32

How is the correct parse form?

Comment: [Duplicte ][1] check it our carefully you get your all answer


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079492/how-to-parse-this-json-with-php

Answer (score 0):

You've declared your foreach wrong, this should work:

```
foreach($obj as $key => $value)
```

1. You had never declared `$array`.
2. `$array[]` is for appending to an array.

Comment: $stmt = $this->db->prepare('INSERT INTO prueba (id,nombre)
                            VALUES (%d,%s)',$key->value1,$key->value2) or die(mysqli_error($this->db));